# JSON request testing

Tags: json, api, testing

In my job, I have to test the API which returns requests in the form of JSON. However I don't have the front end to test. Can someone please tell me a way of testing the API.

Comment: You can use fiddler for testing.

Comment: Can't you wrap a unit-test architecture around your API and call the functions one at a time as if you were the front end?

Comment: I'm not sure from your question whether the problem is that you don't know what tools to use, or that you're unsure what kind of things you could test. Also, are you thinking about testing (as in, probing the API to look for problems), or getting automated checks written for the API?

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "test" like in verifying the API answers correctly to the requests, then you can use [curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) with [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) or [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en).

If you are willing to automate some checks, then you could give [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/) a try.
It is a simple framework to use. You should be able to come up with some tests easily. I wrote a blog post about [using Robot Framework to test Rest API](http://laurent.bristiel.com/robot-framework-rest-and-json/) that could help you.